# Why is app build.gradle showing as plain text(no Elephant icon)?

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I have noticed that one of my build.gradle (app) files now appears as plain text. I'd like to change this back to normal (like the project gradle) so I can properly upgrade/update any libraries.

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm getting the same with an xml

Comment: @Jonathan no, I'm still none the wiser on this. It's quite annoying haha

Comment: @Jonathan scrap that comment....Just found the answer now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what worked for me, assuming Android Studio 3.5: -

Close Android Studio.
Do Start / Run: "%USERPROFILE%\.AndroidStudio3.5\config\options"
    *Where %USERPROFILE% is your user profile folder, for me it's "C:\Users\Jonathan\".*
In that folder there is a "filetypes.xml" file, open it in a text editor like notepad.
Locate the mapping pattern of the file in issue. In my case its was like this: -

```
<application>
  <component name="FileTypeManager" version="17">
    <extensionMap>
      <mapping pattern="toggle_off_color.xml" type="PLAIN_TEXT" />
    </extensionMap>
  </component>
</application>
```

Remove the mapping pattern line of the file not being displayed correctly.
Save the changed filetypes.xml 
Run Android Studio!

I located via a file search on all my hard-drives of files modified since it went wrong (about a month ago) and contained the text of my misbehaving filename; with Agent Ransack: https://www.mythicsoft.com/agentransack/

Comment: That's it! thank you!

I'm on a mac so the file is actually in `.idea/misc.xml`

Comment: That's odd, only because the project itself has an .idea directory with a misc.xml in it, so maybe this can be in several places?  Mine would make "toggle_off_color.xml" a text file no matter which project I opened.  I just don't know the Mac file structure, just saying there may be more than one place to check!  Thanks for the Accept :)

Comment: @Jonathon I double checked this last night and all seems to be fine. Couldn't find it anywhere else.